# Expressions as PowerShell function parameters

Tags: function, powershell, operator-precedence

I have little experience using PowerShell so I was attempting to do some bitwise operations while inputting in binary (purely for readability).  I used the following functions to convert to and from binary and they seem to work.

```
function bin($a){
    return [convert]::ToString($a,2)
}
function unbin($a){
    return [convert]::ToInt64($a,2)
}
```

Then I attempted to run the following:

```
bin(unbin('11001101') -bxor unbin('10110110'))
```

expecting the output `1111011`.

To my surprise I instead get the result `11001101` (the result of `bin(unbin('11001101'))`).

In order to get my code to work I needed to wrap the `unbin` calls in further parentheses and I can't understand why:

```
bin((unbin('11001101')) -bxor (unbin('10110110')))
```

Why are these extra parentheses needed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that function invocation in PowerShell is more akin to invoking cmdlets, *not* .NET methods. So you have a lot of unnecessary parentheses in there and missing a few relevant ones. The following code

```
bin(unbin('11001101') -bxor unbin('10110110'))
```

passes one argument to `bin` (the complete contents of the parentheses), but *three* to the first `unbin` invocation. It's equivalent to

```
unbin '11001101' -bxor "unbin('10110110')"
```

(if I'm not mistaken; details may vary (could be four), but that's the gist of it).

When invoking a PowerShell function, arguments don't get passed in parentheses. And the operands to `-bxor` must be expressions themselves, so any pipelines have to be parenthesized:

```
bin ((unbin '11001101') -bxor (unbin '10110110'))
```

Comment: Okay, that's great, then why do object methods need parentheses e.g. `"test".Split "e"` doesn't work while `"test".Split("e")` does?

Comment: Note I have little experience with PowerShell, so the difference between cmdlets, methods etc is lost on me at this point.

Comment: .NET methods are invoked similarly to how they work in C#. Cmdlets and functions are designed – it's a shell, after all – more like shell commands where arguments are just separated by spaces.